# Is it possible to change default delete action Icon in UITableView edit mode?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I would like to set custom icons for the UITableView delete icon for the table's edit mode.

[image]

I found a way of doing it by setting UITableViewCellEditingStyleNone in editingStyleForRowAtIndexPath method ant then adding my custom button view in the place where that icon should be by subclassing UITableViewCell. source ([enter link description here](http://iosdev12.blogspot.com/2013/06/custom-editing-control-for.html))

I set up a delegate to get the tap even from that button, but with this approach when I tap on this custom button I can't get the cell to slide to the left to reveal red delete button (see the image). So this way, I can just delete the cell by taping only once.

What I need is to mimic the same standard deletion flow with two taps(first on the left delete icon, second on the delete button the slides to the left) but also have my custom icon for the delete on the right.

Is this possible to do?

Any kind of help is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

For fully customize UITableViewcell https://github.com/CEWendel/SWTableViewCell

It will Help you a lot [image]

Comment: Thank you for your response, but I don't need this deep customization, all I need is to change the icon I described above.